# String fields from Records from a SQL Recordset Object not Comparing Correctly VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am retrieving records from a table that needs to look at a column containing string values in order to assign a count to a class to a specific field. For now, I am just using a simple hardcoded series of if statements that compare the string value returned by the current record and a string value that I preset. When executing the code, it passes over the if statement that clearly has the same string value assigned to it.  Example of the code below

```
Dim dbRecord as recordset
Dim sqlString as String
Dim connectionString as string
Dim tmp as string
Dim testVals as new ValClass

connectionString = "example"
sqlString = "Select PCS, StrVal From valTable"

With dbRecord
    .ActiveConnection connectionString
    .Openrecordset sqlString
End With
Do While Not dbRecord.EOF
   tmp = dbRecord!StrVal.Value
   if tmp = "8_6" then
      testVals.v86 = dbRecord!PCS.value
   end if 
   if tmp = "9" then
      testVals.v9 = dbRecord!PCS.value
   end if
   if tmp = "9_6" then
      testVals.v96 = dbRecord!PCS.value
   end if
dbRecord.movenext
Loop
dbRecord.close
```

strVal is a nvarchar(50) in my database. I'm sure there are better ways to go about this, but this has been confusing to me. I am wondering why this is occurring? Any answers are appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: My suspicion is that the underscore is the problem.  In Unicode (nvarchar) there are more than one underscore.  To test the value that is failing, where you think it should succeed, try examining the ASCII value (ASC() function) of the 2nd character, compared with the ASC of "_".    As an aside, use `Select Case` instead of a succession of `If ..End If`, or at the very least use `ElseIf`, as otherwise all tests get examined even when one has succeeded.

Comment: My bad I forgot to add that to my example. The same thing occurs. @HansUp

Comment: Probably unrelated to the error, but when referring to recordset fields, the bang operator `!` follows the name of the field. So, either `dbRecord!StrVal` or `dbRecord("StrVal").Value`.  See this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/guide-to-expression-syntax-ebc770bc-8486-4adc-a9ec-7427cce39a90#:~:text=The%20bang%20operator%20tells%20Access,is%20itself%20a%20table%20object.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback I will test all of these

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at top of every code module? You declare `dbRecord1` yet you use `dbRecord`. One of these is a typo either in your actual code or the posted code.

Comment: @June7 Yes, my bad its not in my actual code just my posted code I will correct sorry

Comment: @KostasK. "`!` follows the name of the field" did you mean "name of the table". Don't quite get your point since OP code uses ! correctly. (And yet Access query builder uses dot - go figure!). If you mean the `.value` is not correct, true ! does not provoke intellisense but .value should still work (Value property reference is not necessary but shouldn't hurt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something different between the string from the database and the string that you use for comparison (you can safely assume that VBA doesn't judge wrong...). However, it is sometimes hard to see the difference. Might be that the underscore character is not the same or that you have invisible characters in the string (blank, Cr, Lf, or some special other characters).

In such cases I use a small routine to dump all characters and their Ascii value to the immediate window:

```
Sub DumpString(s As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim c As String
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        Debug.Print i, AscW(c), c
    Next
End Sub
```

Write, for example, `DumpString tmp` in your code. If it was `"8_6"`, it would show

```
 1    56    8
 2    95    _
 3    54    6
```

If it shows something different, it explains why the `If` fails.

*Disclaimer: I have used this routine already at least once in an answer on SO, but couldn't find it.*

Comment: Thanks this was indeed the problem! For some reason, it added a space at the end.